# How to go back to previous page where some data is already being selected in Angular?

Tags: angular

I have a page "organisation" where I am getting a list of organisation a in drop down. On selecting one of the organisations, I am getting a list of employees working in that organisation in a table.

On selecting one of the employees, I am being redirected to another page, "employee-info," where I can see the information for the employee. Here, I have a back button.

On clicking the back button, I want to redirect from the "employee-info" page to the "organisation" page, where I have selected the organisation and list of employees, based on that organisation.

How can I achieve this?

*organisation.component.html*

```
     <form [formGroup]="organisationForm">
      <div class="form-group row">
        <div class="col-md-6 txt-box">
          <div class="runTextBox">
            <select class="form-control"  (change)="onChangeOrg($event.target.value)"
              formControlName="OrgName" [compareWith]="compareOrgState">
              <option hidden value="" disabled="true">Please select Organisation</option>
              <option *ngFor="let name of getOrgInfo" type="number"                 
             [ngValue]="name.Id"> {{ name.OrgName }}</option>
            </select>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
          <div class="list_table">
            <table class="table tabs links">
              <thead>
                <tr>
                  <th>Employees</th>
                  <th></th>
                  
                </tr>
              </thead>
              <tbody>                    
                <tr *ngFor="let info of getEmpInfo">                      
                  <td (click)="view(info.EmpId)">
                    {{ info.EmpName }}
                  </td>                     
                  <td class="tr">
                    <a> <i class="fa fa-info pr" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
                  </td>                     
                </tr>
              </tbody>
            </table>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
```

*organisation.ts file*

```
       ngOnInit(): void {    
     this.organisationForm = this.fb.group({
       OrgName: [""]
      });
   this.fetchOrgList();  
       }

  fetchOrgList() {
this.service.getOrgList().subscribe((res: any) => {     
  this.getOrgInfo = res;     
  });
 }
  onChangeOrg(value) {   
 this.orgName = value
  this.service.getEmpByOrg(value).subscribe((res: any) => {
  this.getEmpInfo = res;    
 });
 }
   view(v) {    
    this.router.navigate(["/dashboard/employee-info/" + v]);  }
```

On the "employee-info" page, when I click the back button, the whole page gets refreshed. How can I get the selected organisation name and its corresponding employee list in the organisation page?

Answer (score 1):

Ideally, you should be using ngrx state management. But, as a work-around, you can send the 'selected organisation' as 'data' while 'navigating to employee-info', store it in a variable, and while you hit back, send it again as 'data' while 'navigating to organisation', and on `ngOnInit`, check for that 'route-data', set its value to your dropdown.
Like when you're routing to 'employee-info':

```
this.router.navigate(["/dashboard/employee-info/" + v], , { state: { organisation: 'your selected organisation' });  }
```

then, in employee.ts, in `ngOnInit` or `constructor`:

```
this.router.getCurrentNavigation().extras.state.organisation;
```

or `history.state.data`

this should give your selected organisation, do the same while hitting back.